# Dumping available XPC interface and methods

Tags: ios

I'm reading [this article](https://insinuator.net/2020/11/forklift-lpe/), and it says:

```
The following functions are exposed over XPC to the caller:

@protocol _TtP4main21ForkLiftHelperProtcol_
- (void)changePermissions:(NSString *)arg1 permissions:(long long)arg2 reply:(void (^)(NSError *))arg3;
- (void)changeOwner:(NSString *)arg1 owner:(long long)arg2 group:(long long)arg3 reply:(void (^)(NSError *))arg4;
...
```

How can one dump all the protocols and its methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: https://github.com/nygard/class-dump

> class-dump is a command-line utility for examining the Objective-C
> segment of Mach-O files. It generates declarations for the classes,
> categories and protocols. This is the same information provided by
> using 'otool -ov', but presented as normal Objective-C declarations

It works for PrivilegedHelperTools mostly, but not for normal applications.